# Active Directory on Windows Server Standard Group Policy Custom Interface not working

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy

I am trying to create a group policy to lock down specific computers to be used as a kiosk.  I have created a user account in active directory to use on the kiosks and set up a group policy in the domain to just affect that specific account.  Everything is working except my custom interface. I have custom interface enabled and set to
c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -k
When I log into the user account the interface does not load, windows starts normally.

I thought something was wrong with my Policy but all of the other restriction in place work.  What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Value in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` and `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` ?

Comment: Are you asking for current value in the GPO, or on the Machine?

Comment: value on Machine

Answer (score 0):

In a separate OU for computer kiosks and accounts, create a group policy with replacement registry.

Key  : `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

Name : `Shell`

Type : `REG_SZ`

Value: `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -k"`